# Import Python data WITHOUT local resources

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook

We have a corporate environment in which Python is running on AWS, not locally.
Attempts to load data from Excel don't work.      XLRD, pandas etc. can not be used to read local files.

Assuming the data needed is too much to reasonably just type in, what would be the best way to get reasonably large amounts of data into Python?      Is there a widget that can be used to allow arrays to be pasted in?

Ideally, I am thinking of something that would work like this:

- I copy an N by 10 range of cells in Excel
- In python, I select a widget, hit Ctrl-V, and now I have a N x 10 numpy array to work with.

Comment: "In python, I select a widget" ... how do you "select a widget"?  Are you in some kind of IDE? Are you "pasting into sourcecode"? Why not copy your xls over to AWS and read it there?

Comment: AWS consists of a large number of services that can be used to run Python, please be specific about how that is set up as the scope is way too broad; you need to at least narrow your question down to a specific service/platform, for example one of [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/), [AWS Cloud9](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/), or even [AWS EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) at the very start, before even getting to the point of narrowing down to the specifics of what you want to solve/achieve.